# how to check in pandas if element is in column which is an array

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing this situation
let's say I have this dataFrame

```
data = [{'column_1': 1, 'column_2': ['lala', 'lili', 'lele']},{'column_1': 5, 'column_2':['lala', 'lili', 'lolo']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
   column_1            column_2
0         1  [lala, lili, lele]
1         5  [lala, lili, lolo]
```

and I have 3 strings

```
string_1 = 'lele'

string_2 = 'lulu'

string_3 = 'lolo'
```

how could I check if string_1 is in the array of column_2 and return that row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `in` for check membeship in list:

```
string_1 = 'lele'

df1 = df[df['column_2'].apply(lambda x: string_1 in x)]
#alternative
#df1 = df[[string_1 in x for x in df['column_2']]]
print (df1)
   column_1            column_2
0         1  [lala, lili, lele]
```

Another solution is create helper DataFrame and test at least one match per rows by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[pd.DataFrame(df['column_2'].tolist(), index=df.index).eq(string_1).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   column_1            column_2
0         1  [lala, lili, lele]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! you saved my day. One more question, which of those methods would be the more ideal in terms of performance, best practices....? To me seems more easy to read  the filter with list comprehension, but I don't if it is the right one. Thanks again!! ,

Comment: @CapiHidalgo - If performance is important last solution is best option here.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use:

```
df[df['column_2'].apply(pd.Series).eq(string_1).any(axis=1)]
```

Another approach with  [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)

```
df[df['column_2'].explode().eq(string_1).any(level = 0)]
```

**Output**

```
   column_1            column_2
0         1  [lala, lili, lele]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @jezrael pointed to the same solution in his edit :)

Comment: or just `df[df['column_2'].explode().eq(string_1).any(level=0)]`  :)

Comment: @anky_91 I don't know why I thought this only worked with `multiindex`. I think I will never forget it:)